# How to use unix `mv` to rename files with unicode spaces(not U+20)?

Tags: mv, unicode, whitespace

```
$ ls cn*
cn blah blah.txt
$ ls cn\ *
ls: cannot access 'cn *': No such file or directory
$ ls cn*|hexdump -C
00000000  63 6e e2 80 85 62 6c 61  68 c2 a0 62 6c 61 68 2e  |cn...blah..blah.|
00000010  74 78 74 0a                                       |txt.|
$ mv cn blah blah.txt 'cn blah blah.txt'
mv: 'cn blah blah.txt' and 'cn blah blah.txt' are the same file
```

Note: 0xe28085 is the UTF-8 encoding for U+2005(FOUR-PER-EM SPACE) and 0xC2A0 is the UTF-8 encoding for U+A0(NO-BREAK SPACE), and I copy pasted the first argument to `mv` and that is why `'`s are not needed around the file name, because there are *no* normal spaces(U+20) in the file name.

How do I rename the file so that I can type the file's name with a regular space(i.e. U+20)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '*' $'${f//[\u2005\ua0]/ }'
```

U+2005 is usually classified as `blank` or `space`, so you can also do:

```
zmv '*' '${f//[[:blank:]]/ }'
```

Or:

```
zmv '*' '${f//[[:space:]]/ }'
```

To replace any character classified as `blank` or `space` with a U+0020 space (in the names of non-hidden files in the current working directory).

U+00A0 more rarely so as on several systems including GNU ones it's not classified as such on the ground that it is not to be used as separator/delimiter.

Comment: I ended up just `rsync`ing to a computer with a GUI and changing it with the GUI, and `rsync`ing it back.